# Python/AppEngine: Get client browser information

Tags: python, google-app-engine, browser

How can I get client browser information (type, version, etc.) using Python/AppEngine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the User-Agent header:

`user_agent_string = self.request.headers['user-agent']`

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_headers

Comment: (This assumes the webapp framework, which is probably reasonable.)

Comment: You can also just use self.request.user_agent